# Fixed Header Table- AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am relatively new to AngularJs and I am having trouble implementing a Fixed Header on my table. I am using a modified version of a library I am utilizing on other parts of my application with no problem however on this specific table it is not working. I even tried having two separate tables one for the head and one for the body but since the can be dynamic with Angular and a Maximize, this does not work.

**js code:**

```
                     <div id="test"
                         class="panel-body" style="height: 222px; overflow-y: scroll;">
                            <table id="data-sources-table" class="table table-striped drag-drop" fixed-header-custom >
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th style="position: relative">TestProperty</th>
                                    <th style="position: relative" ng-repeat="ds in model.dataSamples"
                                        style="line-height: 16px; vertical-align: top;">
                                        <span tooltip="{{ds.dsName}}"
                                              tooltip-placement="top">
                                            {{ds.dsName.slice(0, 20)}}&nbsp;
                                        </span>
                                        <button class="btn-graphic-only btn-remove" type="button"
                                                ng-show="ds"
                                                ng-model="singleModel"
                                                tooltip="Test data sample"
                                                tooltip-placement="left"
                                                ng-click="removeDs($index)">
                                        </button>
                                    </th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                <tr ng-repeat="(property, linkedDs) in model.properties">
                                    <td ng-class="{'narrow-column': $first}"
                                        ng-style="highlightIfInDetails(model.properties[property])">
                                        <span>
                                            <ul style="margin-bottom: 0px; list-style-type: none; padding: 0px;">
                                                <li dnd-draggable="ds.dsProfile[property]"
                                                    dnd-effect-allowed="copy"
                                                    dnd-copied="dragEnd(property, ds.dsProfile[property])"
                                                    dnd-selected="dropzoneModels.selected = ds.dsProfile[property]">
                                                    <label class="btn-property" style="font-size: 100%;">
                                                        {{property}}
                                                        &nbsp;
                                                    </label>
                                                    <button class="btn-graphic-only btn-remove" type="button"
                                                            ng-model="singleModel"
                                                            tooltip="Remove property from schema"
                                                            tooltip-placement="right"
                                                            ng-click="removeProperty(property)">
                                                    </button>
                                                    <div ng-show="modifySchemaMode === true">
                                                        <!--keep the following on the same line to prevent spaces between values-->
                                                        {{model.properties[property]["main-type"]}}<span
                                                        ng-show="model.properties[property]['main-type']">:{{model.properties[property]["detail"]["detail-type"]}}</span>
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td ng-repeat="ds in model.dataSamples"
                                        ng-style="highlightIfInDetails(ds.dsProfile[property])">
                                        <span class="btn-property">
                                            <label class="btn-property"
                                                   style="font-size: 100%; font-weight: normal;
                                                          -webkit-user-select: none; -moz-user-select: none;
                                                          -ms-user-select: none;"
                                                   unselectable="on"
                                                   single-click="showInDetails1(ds, property, false)"
                                                   ng-dblclick="showInDetails2(ds, property);">
                                                <div ng-show="ds.dsProfile[property]['original-name']">
                                                    <label style="font-size: 100%;">{{ds.dsProfile[property]['original-name']}}</label>
                                                </div>
                                                <!--keep the following on the same line to prevent spaces between values-->
                                                {{ds.dsProfile[property]["main-type"]}}<span
                                                ng-show="ds.dsProfile[property]['main-type']">:{{ds.dsProfile[property]["detail"]["detail-type"]}}</span>
                                                <span class="btn-merge-indicator"
                                                      ng-show="ds.dsProfile[property]['merged-into-schema']">
                                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                                </span>
                                            </label>
                                            <span class="btn-use-check"
                                                  ng-show="ds.dsProfile[property]['used-in-schema']">
                                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                            </span>
                                            <br>
                                            <select name="altNameSelected" id="altNameSelected"
                                                    ng-options="option.name for option in ds.dsProfile[property]['match-names'].availableOptions track by option.id"
                                                    ng-model="ds.dsProfile[property]['match-names'].selectedOption"
                                                    ng-show="ds.dsProfile[property]['match-names'].availableOptions.length > 0"
                                                    ng-change="changeMatchedProperty(ds, property)">
                                            </select>
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
```

**library:**

```
/**
 * AngularJS fixed header scrollable table directive
 * @author Jason Watmore <jason@pointblankdevelopment.com.au> (http://jasonwatmore.com)
 * @version 1.2.0
 */
(function () {
    angular
        .module('anguFixedHeaderTableCustom', [])
        .directive('fixedHeaderCustom', fixedHeaderCustom);

    fixedHeaderCustom.$inject = ['$timeout'];

    function fixedHeaderCustom($timeout) {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: link
        };

        function link($scope, $elem, $attrs, $ctrl) {
            var elem = $elem[0];

            // wait for data to load and then transform the table
            $scope.$watch(tableDataLoaded, function(isTableDataLoaded) {
                if (isTableDataLoaded) {
                    transformTable();
                }
            });

            function tableDataLoaded() {
                // first cell in the tbody exists when data is loaded but doesn't have a width
                // until after the table is transformed
                var firstCell = elem.querySelector('tbody tr:first-child td:first-child');
                return firstCell && !firstCell.style.width;
            }

            function transformTable() {
                // reset display styles so column widths are correct when measured below
                angular.element(elem.querySelectorAll('thead, tbody, tfoot')).css('display', '');

                // wrap in $timeout to give table a chance to finish rendering
                $timeout(function () {
                    // set widths of columns
                    angular.forEach(elem.querySelectorAll('tr:first-child th'), function (thElem, i) {

                        var tdElems = elem.querySelector('tbody tr:first-child td:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')');
                        var tfElems = elem.querySelector('tfoot tr:first-child td:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ')');

                        var columnWidth = tdElems ? tdElems.offsetWidth : thElem.offsetWidth;
                        if (tdElems) {
                            tdElems.style.width = columnWidth + 'px';
                        }
                        if (thElem) {
                            thElem.style.width = columnWidth + 'px';
                        }
                        if (tfElems) {
                            tfElems.style.width = columnWidth + 'px';
                        }
                    });

                    // set css styles on thead and tbody
                    angular.element(elem.querySelectorAll('thead, tfoot')).css('display', 'block');

                    angular.element(elem.querySelectorAll('tbody')).css({
                        'display': 'block',
                        'height': $attrs.tableHeight || 'inherit',
                        'overflow': 'auto'
                    });

                    // reduce width of last column by width of scrollbar
                    var tbody = elem.querySelector('tbody');
                    var scrollBarWidth = tbody.offsetWidth - tbody.clientWidth;
                    if (scrollBarWidth > 0) {
                        // for some reason trimming the width by 2px lines everything up better
                        scrollBarWidth -= 2;
                        var lastColumn = elem.querySelector('tbody tr:first-child td:last-child');
                        lastColumn.style.width = (lastColumn.offsetWidth - scrollBarWidth) + 'px';
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: show your question on fiddler

Comment: thats the problem, if I so it in fiddler it works, until UI build it locally, I think it has something to do with the ng-repeat